# Flutter Error after upgrade to latest version

Tags: flutter, dart

recently updated my flutter to v2.5.3 and I'm getting the following error :

371:41: Error: The getter 'subhead' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subhead'.
  ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead
  ^^^^^^^
  ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/searchable_dropdown-1.1.3/lib/searchable_dropdown.dart:374:16: Error: The getter 'subhead' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subhead'.
  .subhead
  ^^^^^^^

Comment: If I'm not wrong, we have flutter V2.5.2. Can you include your code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The error is somewhat self explanatory: The `subhead` property no longer exists in newer versions of the `TextTheme`, as per the 2018 Material Design guidelines.

If I'm not mistaken you should instead use `subtitle1` as a closest replacement, but feel free to take a look at [the Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) to find out which property to use instead.

See also this other SO question that also uses `subhead`:

[How to use Flutter AppTheme TextTheme without overriding automatic text color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58776282/15469537)